# How to delete data from HTML table using Flask

Tags: html, flask, jinja2, crud

I have an HTML table that is populated from a Flask app. When populating the table I insert a delete button in each row. The button has a link back to the Flask app and contains the records unique ID number. After loading the table I can inspect the button in the browser. The url is what I expected.  `<a href="/processDeleteUser/10" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Delete</a>`

However, when I click the button it passes a different ID to the Flask app `<a href="/processDeleteUser/7"` and deletes the first row of the table instead of the intended row. Please find my code below:

```
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>      
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Password</th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for u in users %}
        {% set uid = u[0] %}
        {% set first = u[2] %}
        {% set last = u[3] %}
        {% set email = u[4] %}
        {% set password = u[5] %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{uid}}</td>
          <td>{{last}}, {{first}}</td>
          <td>{{email}}</td>
          <td>{{password}}</td>          
          <td>
            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#confirmModal">
              <i style="color:red" class="fa fa-times fa-1x"></i>
            </button>
            
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="confirmModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="confirmModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="confirmModalLabel">Confirm Delete</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    Are you sure you want to delete this user?
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <a href="/processDeleteUser/{{uid}}" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Delete</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>          
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}      
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error I think is inside the loop, where you are declaring a modal with the same id multiple times.
I suggest you manage the cancellation through a javascript function invoked by the event `onclick` of the button

```
<tbody>
    {% for u in users %}
    {% set uid = u[0] %}
    {% set first = u[2] %}
    {% set last = u[3] %}
    {% set email = u[4] %}
    {% set password = u[5] %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{uid}}</td>
        <td>{{last}}, {{first}}</td>
        <td>{{email}}</td>
        <td>{{password}}</td>          
        <td>
        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" onclick="myFunction({{uid}})">
            <i style="color:red" class="fa fa-times fa-1x"></i>
        </button>
        </td>          
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}      
</tbody>
```

```
<script>
    function myFunction(id) {
        // handle the cancellation
    }
</script>
```